# Append Columns to Dataframe 1 Based on Matching Column Values in Dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. The first of these dataframes tracks the locations (i.e., ZIP codes) of specific individuals at different time points:

| ID | ZIP 1 | ZIP 2 | ZIP 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55333 | N/A | 55316 |
| 2 | 55114 | 27265 | 27265 |
| 3 | 55744 | 55744 | N/A |

The second dataframe contains several columns of data pertaining to *every* ZIP code in the country (many of which do not appear in `df1`):

| ZIP | State | Tier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01001 | MA | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 27265 | NC | 2 |
| 55114 | MN | 4 |
| 55316 | MN | 7 |
| 55333 | MN | 5 |
| 55744 | MN | 3 |

I would like to merge these dataframes and append the variable names from `df2` to the ends of the corresponding ZIP/time point variable in `df1` to end up with something like this (Note: I removed the ZIP 3 variable for simplicity; I'd still like to append the relevant State and Tier data, as shown for ZIP 1 and ZIP 2):

| ID | ZIP 1 | ZIP 2 | ZIP 1 State | ZIP 2 State | ZIP 1 Tier | ZIP 2 Tier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55333 | N/A | MN | N/A | 5 | N/A |
| 2 | 55114 | 27265 | MN | NC | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 55744 | 55744 | MN | MN | 3 | 3 |

The closest solution I have come up with is to create multiple "merged" dataframes by merging on each individual ZIP code variable in `df1`. This is obviously less than ideal, and does not resolve the variable naming issue either.

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'ZIP 1', right_on = 'ZIP', how = 'left')
merged2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'ZIP 2', right_on = 'ZIP', how = 'left')
merged3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = 'ZIP 3', right_on = 'ZIP', how = 'left')
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated! :-)

Comment: Try `stack` then `map` then `unstack`.

Comment: I think this could be done with joins if you are familiar with them

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
dfs = df1.set_index('ID').stack().rename('ZIP').reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
dfm = dfs.merge(df2)
df_out =dfm.set_index(['ID', dfm.groupby('ID').cumcount() +1]).unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'{i} {j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
    ZIP 1  ZIP 2  ZIP 3 State 1 State 2 State 3 Tier 1 Tier 2 Tier 3
ID                                                                  
1   55333  55316    NaN      MN      MN     NaN      5      7    NaN
2   55114  27265  27265      MN      NC      NC      4      2      2
3   55744  55744    NaN      MN      MN     NaN      3      3    NaN
```